# exporting a function with "exports" does not work if the function has a parameter

Tags: javascript, node.js

i have a function:

```
let createDate = (date) => {
let res = date.split("-");
let year = parseInt(res[0]);
let month = parseInt(res[1]) - 1;
let day = parseInt(res[2]);
console.log(date);
return new Date(year, month, day);
}
```

Now i want to export my function like this:

```
exports.createDate = createDate();
```

This is working for all functions in my file, except of functions that need parameters. The error masseage says something along the lines of "Can't split undefined" or somthing like that. 
Am I missing something. This problem is fairly simple but very hard to put in words to google.

Pleas help. Thank you.

Comment: You're trying to export *the result of calling the function*, not the function itself...

Comment: you're exporting the result of calling `createDate`. if you want to export the function, change the export to `exports.createDate = createDate`. if you really want to export the result of the function, you need to pass a date: `exports.createDate = createDate("whatever")`

Comment: Ahh ok, so the brackets are the problem. It works! Thanks :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not working because you are calling the createDate function in the last line without a parameter.

I think what you want is

```
exports.createDate = createDate;
```

Your version tries to set the **result** of createDate to exports.createDate

Answer (score 0):

another way of doing this:

```js
export default function createDate(date){
    const res = date.split('-');
    const year = parseInt(res[0]);
    const month = parseInt(res[1]) - 1;
    const day = parseInt(res[2]);
    return new Date(year, month, day);
}
```

Also, may I suggest [moment](https://momentjs.com/) for handling/formatting dates